# Not able to configure Apple Id for Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have already created two certificates with Push Notification enabled and tested them working fine but since yesterday I am not able to configure Apple Id for push notification. I have followed [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) and generated new Apple Id, clicked configure, checked enable push notification checkbox, clicked configure for production(or development), generated certificate request authority from key chain, and uploaded when it has asked during certificate generation. But when I click continue nothing happens...!! Could anyone please tell me what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is but I have the same problem. I suspect that is it the WWDC intermediate certificate being duplicated on the machine I am requesting from (or something similar).

Comment: What you mean by "WWDC intermediate certificate being duplicated on the machine I am requesting from.."?

Comment: not sure what's wrong on my machine, I am able to generate certificate from my laptop but not from my MAC machine.!!

Comment: Check the keychains on both machines

Comment: wht to check in tht? I am able to generate CSR but uploading to Apple site to generate *.cer doesn't do anything!

Comment: I had the same problem, I think that's it's a problem from Apple website.

Comment: ...but did you able to solve it? I am still not able to generate certificate on my work PC!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Chrome browser. Just switched to Safari and everything is going smooth then onwards!!